# C# WPF Programatically created DataTemplate Dockpanel in Stackpanel has no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, datatemplate, frameworkelement

I'm trying to dynamically create a datatemplate for a listbox. This is for a Custom UserControl. This UserControl has a **DependencyProperty** which accepts any types of **IEnumerable<>**.

This works fine... But the Output is always

- Property / Value
- Property / Value

if the objects contains 2 Properties. But i want that the properties are arranged side by side. Like:

Object 1:

- Porperty / Value Property / Value

Object 2:

- Property / Value Property / Value

So where am i wrong ? i'm making first a Stackpanel and in the Stackpanel, Dockpanels which contain the Labels.

Here is a little preview how it looks at the moment.[image]

So this is my code to create the datatemplate:

```
    DataTemplate _NewData = new DataTemplate();
    FrameworkElementFactory _template = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));

                foreach (var _FProperty in view.CurrentItem.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    FrameworkElementFactory _firstTemplateChild = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DockPanel));

                    FrameworkElementFactory _childOneForDock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));

                    _childOneForDock.SetValue(Label.ContentProperty, _FProperty.Name);
                    _firstTemplateChild.AppendChild(_childOneForDock);
                    FrameworkElementFactory _childTwoForChild = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
                    _childTwoForChild.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding(_FProperty.Name));
                    _firstTemplateChild.AppendChild(_childTwoForChild);
                    _template.AppendChild(_firstTemplateChild);
                }
                _NewData.VisualTree = _template;
                ListBoxInPopUp.ItemTemplate = _NewData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default orientation of a `StackPanel` is vertical.

You'll need to set the orientation to horizontal to get the contents to appear side-by-side.

In the code example in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation.aspx) it states:

```
<!-- The items under this StackPanel are stacked Vertically. Note that Orientation 
     has a default value of "Vertical" but in this example the property is explicitely
     set for clarity. -->
```

<sup>(spelling mistakes are all theirs)</sup>

Also the default value of the `DockPanel.Dock` property is Left, though I'm not sure if that's a factor in this case.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.dock.aspx)

Comment: but shouldn`t the dockpanel in the stackpanel arrange them side by side ?

Comment: @Mark - you're not setting the `Dock` property either (or have I missed that bit?)

Comment: No because when i normally not set the Dock property my items in a Dockpanel are arranged side by side ? I tried it with  _childOneForDock.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Left); and _childTwoForChild.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Right); that hasen't any effect :(

Comment: @Mark I know this is way late, but did you try setting  `dockPanel.LastChildFill = true;` to get your 2nd child to be fully right justified?