# WPF dynamically set text wrapping property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have DataGridControl which creates columns dynamically based on a configuration from DB. I need wrap text in some cases. The code behind this looks somehow like this:

```
public class MyDataGridControl : DataGrid
{
    ...
    private void CreateColumns()
    {
        foreach (var colDef in GridDefinition.Columns)
        {
            ...
            dataGridColumn = new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding(colDef.Name) };
            ...

            //Wrap
            if(WrapColumn != null && columnDefinition.Name.Equals(WrapColumn))
            {
                dataGridColumn.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
            }

            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My problem is that setting TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty does not work. Text does not wrap and I can't find out why. The grid control above does not have any WPF code. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What happens instead of wrapping? "Does not work" sounds very specific to you when you're looking at the results, but I'm not looking at the results.

Comment: "Does not work" means text is not wrapped when the width of column is lower than text size. Text is overflowing the col.

Comment: By "overflowing" do you mean the end is cut off at the edge of the column?

Comment: Exactly as you wrote

Answer (score 0):

`TextBlock.TextWrapping` isn't an attached property, so you can't apply it to `DataGridTextColumn`, only to `TextBlock`. I was able to get text to wrap in a DataGrid by using a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. I just put a `TextBlock` in the `CellTemplate` and put `TextWrapping` on it.

XAML would look like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Text="{Binding Name}" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I've never programatically created a `DataTemplate`. Looks like [this question may be doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4788137/424129).

Comment: Yes this should work but as I mentioned above I dont have WPF like this. I need do this programatically. I'll check the link you wrote.